# How to move texts from left to right in iPhone app programmatically?

Tags: ios, text, uiview, uilabel, uiviewanimation

Am working in iPhone application. I want to show some texts/alerts from webservice in my app like moving texts (Scrolling with animation from left to right). I don't know how to do this?

The alert messages from webservice are vary in lenghts and the alert message count also vary. I want to show one by one in Scrolling in top of my UIViewController with animation. It is possible to do in iPhone apps? If it is possible means anyone please help me to do this? I don't have any idea. Please help me on this. Looking forward your help. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I have tried stackoverflow.com/questions/1369314/how-to-add-moving-text-in-iphone. It is for animate texts from bottom-top. I want to show left-right. I have tried to change the code but i'm not able to fix this. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: i would suggest you to use UIWebView if you want to show marquee in your app.

Comment: Like as marquee in HTML. And one more thing that is the height is fixed and width is variable or both are variable?

Comment: @Leena Am receiving the alert messages in String format. Sometimes it returns 5-10 sometimes it returns above 10. The alert messages lenght is differing. And also how to show NSString (Strings) in UIWebView? Thank you.

Comment: @0x7fffffff I have tried this stackoverflow.com/questions/1369314/how-to-add-a-moving-text-in-iphone. It is working for down-up. But i have changed the code for left to right. But i am able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

Set your label at default position with X=0 and Width = 320
Y and Height according to your need

write this code where you want to perform animation

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5];

lbl.frame = CGRectMake(320, lbl.frame.origin.y, lbl.frame.size.width, lbl.frame.size.height);

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

*Note:*
This code is for Left to right change  CGRectMake argument according to make it right to left.

**EDIT**: (After First Comment)

Put this animation code in NSTimer method which run after every 5 or 6 second and in that method
That Method look something like this:

- Change Text Of Label
- Set default position
- Animation code

Good luck

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I need one more help from you. I have received 5-10 alert messages from Webservice. I have to scroll all messages one by one. Your code working fine for single message. How to show all messages one by one? Any idea. And aslo i have a button to go forward and backward to view the messages. Please help me to do this. Am very confuse on this animations. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have done that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
int i = 0;
float width = 0.0;
float origin_x = 0.0;

for (NSString *s in arrList)
{
    CGSize size;
    NSRange r;

    size = [s sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"*****" size:14.0] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(10000.0, 35.0) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    width = (size.width + 12.0 + 10.0);

    UIView *viewTopStory = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(origin_x, 0.0, width, 35.0)] autorelease];
    viewTopStory.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    UIImageView *imgStar = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"] ] autorelease];
    imgStar.frame = CGRectMake(5, 8.0, 12, 12);
    [viewTopStory addSubview:imgStar];

    UILabel *lblTopstory = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(22.0, 2.75, size.width, 30.0)] autorelease];
    lblTopstory.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"*****" size:14.0];
    lblTopstory.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    lblTopstory.text = s;
    [viewTopStory addSubview:lblTopstory];

    [_viewTopStory addSubview:viewTopStory];

    CGRect frame = _viewTopStory.frame;
    frame.size.width += width;
    _viewTopStory.frame = frame;

    origin_x += width;

    i++;
}

CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation
                                  animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
//NSMutableArray *marrframeValues = [[[NSMutableArray alloc]init] autorelease];
CATransform3D Translation0 = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
CATransform3D Translation4 = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(_viewTopStory.frame.size.width, 0.0, 0.0);

NSArray *frameValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:Translation0], [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:Translation4],
                        nil];

[animation setValues:frameValues];

NSArray *frameTimes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0], nil];

[animation setKeyTimes:frameTimes];

animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards;
//animation.autoreverses = YES;
animation.repeatCount = 10000;
animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
animation.duration = 200.0;

[_viewTopStory.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"popup"];
```

I've already placed the _viewTopStory with initial fixed frame after then I've modified the frame depending on the text.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I have tried your code but it is overlaping multiple messages in UILabel. Could you please help me? Am working on your code. Thanks.

Comment: You have to set the frames according to your requiremnts. I've set the frames according to  my requirements.

Comment: Hi, I have done that functionality. Thank you for your great help. thanks again.